# Define Javascript object using dynamic string literal as object propery name

Tags: javascript

Needing to do:

```
var some = {
    `${foo1}_${foo2}`: bar
}
```

but this gives a syntax error though I must do it somehow. How?

Answer (score 0):

you can suppose object as hashmap and access properties via `[]`

```js
var foo1 = 'a';
var foo2 = 'b';
var some = {};
some[foo1+'_'+foo2] = 'test';

console.log(some.a_b);
```